# Retrieve specific key under Uid and use for query firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a Firebase query using the value of a key in a particular node.The particular node is the currently signed in user.

How do I get the value of the particular key under the currently signed in user's node and use it to query my database?

This is my code:

```
    final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            halls1 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Male").child(user_id).getValue(User.class).getHalls();
            halls2 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Female").child(user_id).getValue(User.class).getHalls();
         }
        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(user_id)){
                query = databaseReference.child("Female").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls1);

            }
            else{
                query = databaseReference.child("Female").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls2);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });
```

DATABASE STRUCTURE

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "Female" : {
      "WwBjblOo8maSP5PXlYviONrS3Oo2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2Fecf2758a-5628-4297-bcb3-e8c3f138cbbd.jpeg?alt=media&token=1ca6067d-6c08-49b9-a2bf-6a8315ada067",
        "halls" : "Kwapong",
        "levels" : "300",
        "username" : "merylstre"
      },
      "X8c80zaY0kfT5KVoTFHbhPIEG9z2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F51dc26a1-45e8-4897-9c2f-14caf8e79cc5.jpeg?alt=media&token=90818c1e-167e-4799-bc29-b3fe52529cd2",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "hashcodef"
      }
    },
    "Male" : {
      "2EXejmHoMlWoKSDb5APvSt8do5e2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F83ca18a0-63a5-477a-ab1e-b2732b3ebfa1.jpeg?alt=media&token=b8626221-a67c-48e3-b958-d373c9f63c69",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "fillman"
      },
      "BW79oGosAIhdxDxYXbtHbSbC0D23" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F90b93b19-230b-4f28-b394-358d0c516c5c.jpeg?alt=media&token=0c82c272-d6fb-46e8-a6cf-581f5501de7b",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "radjames"
      },
      "Mop4hbS0zne6QS3woum1udLgwqf1" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F78621a8b-7d67-413c-9e57-f378e60ba41e.jpeg?alt=media&token=3982ee0a-2a34-41b3-9250-f0884531ee86",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "radjohn"
      },
      "VvnOY3k7Cwa36bJW55JiZDJRwPN2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F1ac7080f-8db8-49a7-bb76-34b007deb839.jpeg?alt=media&token=6d100527-80d3-49b3-b0ae-617dd55e64de",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "ciryadams"
      },
      "WOT11DVkoVb9owzK4qKHbvT4ODF2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F3fda02ae-c577-4a4a-86c1-cadcaf518c97.jpeg?alt=media&token=5baf2a79-b14c-4e28-b7bb-77e55ae08e55",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "markzuck"
      },
      "dbnmFoC4hnSCsXsxJgVO0Q7GYx13" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F2366c787-fb16-4049-9c7d-3d0c2a09ab9b.jpeg?alt=media&token=25bda8dd-ab24-4b9b-8299-534e49bf9ed4",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "dasdsada"
      },
      "iqZfSgGNpPZ4HDtOUuHYZ1u8x273" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2Fc52cd467-05b9-4ece-8085-4cdf502839c5.jpeg?alt=media&token=4c9eb36e-4644-49ec-85eb-c2fef38ca50e",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "maameEsi"
      },
      "jj9yycmDNbZwiPVTLrRyYZheM702" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F5c4a34b2-bc7b-43e7-8b00-7e0bf63ff252.jpeg?alt=media&token=59a11905-a67d-48ea-9f16-10ffd3915876",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "hashcode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication users are not automatically stored in the Firebase Database. If they are stored in your database, you've written code to do so. If that's the case, please share a representative snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshots) that shows how the users are stored.  You can get this JSON by clicking the Export JSON link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: I just shared a snippet of the JSON @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: How do you know based on `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` under which node (`Female` or `Male`) the user is stored? If you don't know that without looking at the database, you will always have to check under both nodes.

Comment: Yes I am checking both nodes.I dont know if that is efficient but from the way my database is set up, it seems like the only way.I want to retrieve the value of the "halls" key under the currentUser's node and use it for my query@FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

To read the user in case they're under the `Male` node:

```
final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
final DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = root.child("Male").child(user_id);

userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            halls1 = (String) snapshot.getValue(User.class).getHalls();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("User "+user_id+" does not exist under /Male");
        }

     }
    @Override
    public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
```